# На современном firefox не отображается шрифт

Tags: firefox, css

в остальных беспроблем отображается. Что еще добавить сюда?

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Europe_Ext';
   src: url('font/europeextnormal.eot');
   src: url('font/europeextnormal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('font/europeextnormal.woff') format('woff'),
   url('font/europeextnormal.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('font/europeextnormal.svg#europeextnormal') format('svg');
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
            }
```

p.s.   в файрфоксе файрбаг видит шрифт Europe_Ext и даже когда наводишь мыш показывает а на самом браузере отображается Times New Roman:(

Comment: Кэш браузера почистите.

Comment: не помогло, странно..(

Comment:  1. Покажите как вы подключаете шрифт в CSS
 2. От куда вы брали шрифт в woff, например?

Comment: ну, как я подключаю уже выше видно, а woff формат я сгенерировал ttf формат вот в этом сайте http://fontface.codeandmore.com/index.php,

Comment: @bemulima, попробуйте воспользоваться [этим сервисом](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). И не отображается только кириллица или и латиница тоже?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, уже решил вопрос

Comment: Я про woff спросил потому, что не все сервисы хороши. У меня тоже было, что шрифт не работал. А потом я воспользовался другим конвертером и все стало гуд.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Europe_Ext';
    src: url('font/europeextnormal.eot');
    src: local('Europe_Ext'), local('Europe_Ext'),
    url('font/europeextnormal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('font/europeextnormal.woff') format('woff'),
    url('font/europeextnormal.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('font/europeextnormal.svg#europeextnormal') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: Не удачное решение. У вас данный шрифт есть. А строка:

    src: local('Europe_Ext'), local('Europe_Ext')

означает примерно следующее: "*что браузер не будет подгружать внешние файлы, если такой шрифт уже установлен на компьютере пользователя*". А если такого шрифта не будет?

Comment: Я думаю вы вопрос не решили. У вас шрифт установлен и берется из local. Попробуйте удалить шрифт и проверить подключается ли он в firefox.

Comment: Точно вы правы, щас буду пробовать по другому

Comment: Попробуйте, всеже, заново конвертнуть шрифты. Тут, например http://convertfonts.com/otf-to-woff.php

Comment: Во! Теперь сработал:) Спасибо psyho_Octopus, все дело в конвертере было оказывается. src: local('Europe_Ext') - убрал), ссылка то что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Была подобная проблема. Удали тег base